# Manifest.json Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, manifest.json

Hello I pushed a react/express project up to heroku (https://polar-oasis-57801.herokuapp.com/) and received the following errors in the console:
[Chrome console error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyMuL.png)

I tried looking up this error and it seems that I need to change something in my manifest.json file but I'm not sure. Any advice would help. Here's my manifest file:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

And also my project on Github: https://github.com/bernar83/cat-cards

Comment: Usually such errors mean the JSON parsed is not valid JSON. A quick check of the file you linked seems to suggest it is valid JSON. Is it possible the manifest.json is changed somehow during the deploy process?

Comment: "Unexpected token `<`" usually means you're trying to parse HTML instead of JSON. Looking at the data returned by the server for https://polar-oasis-57801.herokuapp.com/cat-cards/manifest.json you can see that that's exactly what's happening. The server is returning an HTML document instead of your JSON file. (It's doing the same thing for your `.js` and `.css` files.)

Comment: I just got the same error and after some hours I fixed it changing the `start_url` in the `manifest.json` to `"start_url": "./index.html",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this change `"/cat-cards/"` in my server.js file so now it's `app.use("/cat-cards/", express.static("client/build"));`. Adding that change and pushing to Heroku made my website work. This helped me: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1812#issuecomment-286511320

Answer (score 13):

This error means that the request to `manifest.json` does not return a valid JSON response. Probably it returns an HTML, given the fact that it fails because of a starting `<`.

Be sure to link the `manifest.json` correctly and make sure to preserve its integrity in the deployment process. Try to navigate to `http://yoururl/manifest.json` and check the result.

EDIT1: it seems like your link to the manifest is broken. In https://github.com/bernar83/cat-cards/blob/master/client/public/index.html , try replacing

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

with

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
```

EDIT2: Just checked your Heroku link and can confirm the error. Your page tries to find the `manifest.json` under the path `/cat-cards/manifest.json` which is wrong. It should only be `manifest.json`

Comment: I changed the link to just `manifest.json` and it removed the error message about the manifest file but looking at the console now in my recently deployed heroku site I still get the first two errors in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyMuL.png. Any ideas on how to remove the uncaught syntax error?

Comment: you have to fix the links to your javascript files aswell

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place but could you clarify where I can find those javascript links? I'm assuming it's in the `client/build/index.html` file where the manifest link was in but I was not able to find javascript links in it.

Comment: Actually removing `homepage` from `package.json` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I solve it by:

1. Go into package.json file in your react app.
2. You will see the homepage attribute at the top, remove it either copy that URL.

- If you remove it then again create build and use that build in your `express.static('./build')`.
- If you copy it then use that url in your `app.use("that copied url" , express.static('./build'))` in your express server file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I'll add it since this is the SO post I ended up at while trying to figure it out. I'd included some generated favicon markup to my "JS not allowed" file. My manifest.json is in my src/ directory, so the pasted in markup was referencing a manifest that wasn't in my public root. The boilerplate code then returned the "JS not allowed here" EJS HTML *as the actual return value for the manifest.json*, so the browser saw it as malformed JSON... Not ideal.

So, if your router is going to return this sort of thing for bad HTTP requests, like Ant Design Pro does, it could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I faced this problem and struggled a lot with it then I follow This helped me: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1812#issuecomment-286511320 link. it definitely works. I am thankful to the person who shares this link.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include some context and the essential parts of the answer here, then provide the link for reference. Link-only answers become invalid when the linked page changes or goes offline. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check the index.html inside build and inside your public folder. I had the same issues and just found that issue was with Html nothing else.

Thanks
Binod Singh

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today. The issue for my team was that in the server.js file, the `app.use(routes)`
line was above the the static assets
`app.use(express.static("client/build"))`

Moving it below allowed the site to deploy to heroku appropriately.